# How can I find the area of ​a quadrilateral drawn with BGI in c programming

Tags: c, coordinates, calculation, area, bgi

How can I find the area of ​​a shape (triangle, quadrilateral and pentagon) drawn with BGI, whose coordinate points are given in C programming, by adding the unit squares inside the quadrilateral and through which the side lines pass?

I drew it in BGI with the coordinate points given in the figure, but I need to find its area by adding the unit squares within which the edge lines pass. I need this for a project.

```
void dortgen_alani(int sekil_ciz[][2])
{
    int x[4], y[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        x[i] = sekil_ciz[i][0];
        y[i] = sekil_ciz[i][1];
        
        putpixel(x[i], y[i], WHITE); // Noktaları işaretle
    }

    int toplamBirimKare = 0;

    int minX = x[0], minY = y[0];
    int maxX = x[0], maxY = y[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (x[i] < minX) minX = x[i];
        if (x[i] > maxX) maxX = x[i];
        if (y[i] < minY) minY = y[i];
        if (y[i] > maxY) maxY = y[i];
    }
 
    for (int i = minX; i < maxX; i++) {
        for (int j = minY; j < maxY; j++) {
            int icindeMi = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                int x1 = x[k];
                int y1 = y[k];
                int x2 = x[(k + 1) % 4];
                int y2 = y[(k + 1) % 4];

                int xMin = x1 < x2 ? x1 : x2;
                int xMax = x1 > x2 ? x1 : x2;
               
                int yMin = y1 < y2 ? y1 : y2;
                int yMax = y1 > y2 ? y1 : y2;

                if (i >= xMin && i < xMax && j >= yMin && j < yMax) {
                    if ((i - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (j - y1) * (x2 - x1) < 0) {
                        icindeMi = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (icindeMi) {
                putpixel(i, j, BLUE);
                toplamBirimKare++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Dortgenin alani (birim karelerle): %d birim kare\n", toplamBirimKare / 100);
}
```

This code does not calculate correctly.

Comment: Aside: a pentagon is not a quadrilateral.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you only need one formula and that's the one to calculate [the area of an irregular polygon](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/area-irregular-polygons.html).

Comment: Decompose polys to triangles, calculate areas with Heron and sum them up.

Comment: @ulix Using Herons formula to calculate the area of triangles isn't needed and would be more expensive than just calculating the area under each side, sum up and divide by 2. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/GMo1738hW)

Comment: [Same question except for C++ and OpenCV.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656045/how-to-count-all-non-zero-pixels-within-each-polygon-area-efficiently)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Calculating the mathematical area does not give the number of pixels touched (including interior and border pixels).

Comment: @ulix: Calculating the mathematical area does not give the number of pixels touched (including interior and border pixels).

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, that's true. I'm not sure if that's what OP wants but it may very well be.

Comment: Are you trying to 'fill' an irregular polygon? If so, I think that's a different question.

Comment: Are you supposed to approximate the area by using something like getpixel() and summing all the pixels within the shape(s) that are not painted?  -- or pixels that are painted -- something to this effect?  If the shape is filled, you could go left to right and top to bottom across the entire screen with getpixel() -- and sum all ( and only ) the painted pixels.

Comment: Please come back and answer a question or two because one or more of us aren't sure just what you are asking or how to help you.

Comment: Yes, with C programming in BGI, I need to find the area of ​​a shape drawn according to its coordinates by adding the number of unit squares or pixels inside and through which the edge lines pass

Comment: So I need to use this to approximate the area of ​​the shape. Of course, we cannot find the exact area by adding the unit squares.

Comment: Edit the question to make it clear what problem you want to solve. Specifically, is the ideal goal to find the area of the mathematical polygon whose vertices are given by the list of points (the exact area if drawn on an ideal plane) or is it to count the total number of pixels that share any point with the polygon and its interior (the number of pixels affected when drawing the shape on a display)? And, if the latter, do you want to do this from the list of points alone, without rendering the shape if we do not need to, or is the shape always rendered and we can count from the rendering?

Comment: In particular, note that if you want the area of the polygon and figured counting pixels was a way to approximate that, that is not necessary. There is a simple method for calculating the area of a polygon from the coordinates of its vertices.

Comment: Blast from the past!

Answer (score 1):

Find the area of a screen image/object by reading screen pixels of the object.

This is a solution for finding the area of specific geometric objects drawn on the screen in graphics mode. It reads screen pixels to discern exact location and general nature/shape of the object, and ultimately its area.

UPDATED VERSION:

Tested objects: triangle, rectangle, quadrilateral, pentagon, circle, and more. Test bed showing proof of concept with runnable code and numerous test cases is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7hnP5szM8).

Logic: Assume all the unpainted screen pixels are zero (ie: color black). We traverse the screen left to right and top to bottom examining every pixel to locate the image object and its interior.  Expectation is that the image only exists as an outline (not filled), and is drawn with some non-zero pixel color.

From there, we use a common floodfill algorithm to fill the interior of the object with a specified color.  At last, we analyze the screen summing all the painted pixels: this is the object's area.

This code is designed for Turbo C -- per OP's reference: "drawn in "BGI" (Borland Graphics Interface). However, the logic of the code is portable, so we only need to replace putpixel() and getpixel() with the applicable API to work on any platform.

putpixel() and getpixel() are both simulated -- using a virtual screen buffer -- in this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TARGET_COLOR 0
#define FLOOD_COLOR  2
#define EDGE_COLOR   1

#define SCREEN_W 40
#define SCREEN_H 20

unsigned short screen[SCREEN_H][SCREEN_W]; 

/* This virtual screen has a 10x15 rectangle "drawn" in it.
** -- Do you see it? -- rectangle area should be 150.
*/
#define RECT_AREA 150
unsigned short screen_rect[SCREEN_H][SCREEN_W] = {
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};



/* Test bed versions of Turbo C's getpixel() and putpixel()
* Both use screen array as a virtual screen */
unsigned getpixel(int x, int y)
{
    return screen[y][x];
}
void putpixel(int x, int y, int color)
{
    screen[y][x] = color;
}


/*---------------------------------------------------------------------
    disp_matrix()  -- Helper function: display the image/matrix/table.  
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void disp_matrix(int wdth, int hgt)
{
    int xxx,yyy;

    for (yyy = 0; yyy < hgt; yyy++) 
    {
        for (xxx = 0; xxx < wdth; xxx++) 
        {
        int ch;
            switch(getpixel(xxx,yyy))
            {
                case 0:
                    ch = ' ';
                break;
                
                case 1:
                    ch = '1';
                break;

                case FLOOD_COLOR:
                    ch = '2';
                break;
                
                default:
                    ch = getpixel(xxx,yyy)+'0';
                break;
            }
            putchar(ch); 
        }
        putchar('\n'); 
    }
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------

    get_image_area()

    Use after floodfill complete. 
    Count all non-zero pixels and return count.
*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
int get_image_area(int wdth, int hgt)
{
    int xxx,yyy,sum=0;

    for (yyy = 0; yyy < hgt; yyy++) 
    {
        for (xxx = 0; xxx < wdth; xxx++) 
        {
            if(getpixel(xxx,yyy) != 0)
                sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    find_image_interior()

    Given a rendered, non-filled screen image, span screen top to bottom.
    For each screen pixel, scan north, south, east and west.  
    If an edge is found in each and every direction, return 1 (success) and provide
    interior coordinate.    Else return 0 (fail).
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int find_image_interior(int *px, int *py, int wdth, int hgt)
{
    int xxx,yyy,x,y;
    int east = 0, west = 0, north = 0, south = 0;

    for(y=0; y<hgt; y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x<wdth; x++)
        {
            east = west = north = south = 0;
            xxx = x,yyy =y;
            while(!west && --xxx > -1 )
            {
                if( getpixel(xxx,yyy) == EDGE_COLOR)
                {
                    west = 1; /* West search was a success.  Market*/
                }
            }
            xxx = x,yyy =y;
            while(!east && ++xxx < wdth )
            {
                if( getpixel(xxx,yyy) == EDGE_COLOR)
                {
                    east = 1; /* East search was a success.  Market*/
                }
            }
            xxx = x,yyy =y;
            while(!north && --yyy > -1 )
            {
                if( getpixel(xxx,yyy) == EDGE_COLOR)
                {
                    north = 1; /* North search was a success.  Market*/
                }
            }
            xxx = x,yyy =y;
            while(!south  && ++yyy < hgt)
            {
                if( getpixel(xxx,yyy) == EDGE_COLOR)
                {
                    south = 1; /* North search was a success.  Market*/
                }
            }
            if((east+west+north+south) == 4)
            {
                printf("Image interior found at %d x %d\n", x, y);
                *px = x;
                *py = y;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    flood_fill()

    The basic floodfill algo/code is thanks to user Malcolm McLean [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086081/3130521)
    and looks like this:

    void floodfill(int **tab, int u, int v, int i int j)
    {
       if(tab[i][j] == u)
       {
           tab[i][j[ = v;
           floodfill(tab, u, v, i+1, ,j);
           floodfill(tab, u, v, i-1, j);
           floodfill(tab, u, v, i, j -1);
           floodfill(tab, u, v, i, j +1);
       }
    } 
    
    Adapted for this app to stay in screen bounds and image interior.

    Returns: sum of updated pixels.  (Unused)

*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int flood_fill(int start_x, int start_y, int wdth, int hgt)
{
    int sum = 0;

    /* Bounds check */
    if (start_x > wdth-1 || start_x < 0 || start_y > hgt-1 || start_y < 0)
        return sum;
    
    /* If pixel not proper target color, exit */
    if (getpixel(start_x,start_y) != TARGET_COLOR)
        return sum;

    /* Mark the image pixel with the floodfill char */
    putpixel(start_x,start_y,FLOOD_COLOR);
    sum = 1;

    /* Basic floodfill algo -- recursive: check pixel above, below, left and rgt.
        
        Added: what directions are legal? We want to stay within our image boundaries.
        Examine Up, Down, Left, Right pixels for image edge.
        If edge not found, proceed with recursive call:
    */
    if(getpixel(start_x+1, start_y) != EDGE_COLOR)
        sum +=  flood_fill(start_x+1, start_y,  wdth, hgt);
    if(getpixel(start_x-1,start_y) != EDGE_COLOR)
        sum +=  flood_fill(start_x-1, start_y,  wdth, hgt);
    if(getpixel(start_x,start_y+1) != EDGE_COLOR)
        sum +=  flood_fill(start_x,   start_y+1, wdth, hgt); 
    if(getpixel(start_x, start_y-1) != EDGE_COLOR)
        sum +=  flood_fill(start_x,  start_y-1, wdth, hgt);

    return sum;
}


int main() 
{
    int wdth = SCREEN_W, hgt = SCREEN_H;
    int xxx, yyy, area;

    /* Setup each test case by copying the image data to the virtual screen buffer*/
    memcpy(screen, screen_rect, sizeof(screen));

    disp_matrix(wdth, hgt);  /* Display before floodfill() */

    /* Normally in image floodfill, a user will use a pointing device to instruct the app
    * where to begin the floodfil1.  We don't have that luxury; we search: */
    if(!find_image_interior(&xxx,&yyy, wdth, hgt) )
    {
        printf("Couldn't find image interior!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    flood_fill(xxx, yyy, wdth, hgt); /* Do the floodfill beginning with coords provided by find */
    area = get_image_area(wdth, hgt); /* Finally get the sum of all non-zero, painted pixels */
    disp_matrix(wdth, hgt);   /* Display after floodfill() */
    /* Tell stats/image area */
    printf("Rectangle area should be: %d.  Computed area is: %d\n", RECT_AREA, area); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                                            
                   1111111111               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1        1               
                   1111111111               
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
    Image interior found at 16 x 2
                                            
                   1111111111               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1222222221               
                   1111111111               
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
    Rectangle area should be: 150.  Computed area is: 150
```

Comment: Consider a polygon with a left edge that is a diagonal line that is more horizontal than vertical. The rendering of this line will at places contain two adjacent pixels in the same row. For the first, the code in this answer will set `inside_object` to 1 and increment `edge_count` to 1. For the second, since `edge_count` is not zero, it will set `inside_object` to 0. Then the code will not count the following pixels for `inside_object` even though they are inside the polygon.

Comment: Code is updated/fixed per Eric's finding.

Comment: Better. What happens if the quadrilateral is not convex? Consider a V shape.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- like an inverted isosceles triangle?

Comment: It is open on one end, like . Whether it is up or down does not matter. Connect the points (10, 0), (20, 20), (10, 10), (0, 20) and back to (10, 0).

Comment: Code is once again updated/improved per Eric's kind suggestion/finding.  Thanks Eric!  A test case is added (at godbolt link in answer) per your suggestion .  Look for the "flying V."